# PrintPreviewDialog does not display an embedded font correctly

Tags: .net, printing, fonts, truetype, embedded-fonts

My Winform program prints some text using `PrintDocument`, `Graphics.DrawString` method and an embedded font (a custom true type font).
The printer handles the custom font ok. But the `PrintPreviewDialog` does not, it uses a different font to render the text.
How can I fix this?